# How to change the background colour of a QWidget inside QStackedWidget using css?

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface

How do I change the background colour of the QWidget in a QStackedWidget using Qt css?

```
ProjectPage* p = new ProjectPage(this);
ui.stackedWidget->addWidget(p);
```

My `ProjectPage` is a custom `QWidget` built in the Qt designer. Currently I tried changing the background color of `ProjectPage` in the designer and that has failed to work. It's a failure because the color of the background when displayed in my application is the default color I set all `QWidget` using the css, the only exception is all labels and buttons on my `ProjectPage` had their colour changed.

I'm currently unable to find the `QstackedWidget` css documentation.

---

**Note:** background images work fine, I'm exploring the possibility that this is related to me having set a default image for all QWidgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is caused by using the css code below.

```
QWidget {
    background-image: url(:/texture.png);
}
```

By defining a default texture all background colour you set becomes hidden behind this texture.

The solution is to remove the default texture from `QWidget` or load a new texture with the colour you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
setStyleSheet ("YourQWidgetBasedPageClass#nameOfYourPageWidget {background: white;}");
```

if you're overriding the `paintEvent` of that custom widget class, remember to call the default `QWidget::paintEvent` somewhere in your implementation or the css will not kick in

note that the # name is only necessary if you want to select a specific widget. Also, the color can be any of the html style names: white, red, purple, etc... as well as #XXXXXX style  colors or using RGB(...)

Comment: I'm using the default paintEvent() method. And I've made the background change in the designer so there is no way I got the wrong name.

Comment: you can set the style sheet on the specific widget in designer as i described above